# How to Use Javascript Remoting Namespace From Managed Package

Tags: javascript, managed-package, javascript-remoting, namespace

We have a managed package.
In order to implement a sandbox / release management process for our application we have made all our code dynamic.

We populate via a custom setting the name of the org's namespace.

How do we implement a dynamic namespace for javascript remoting?
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting.htm

```
[namespace.]controller.method(
    [parameters...,]
    callbackFunction,
    [configuration]
);
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to have a conditional namespace in a remote action invocation is like this:

```
(namespace||window).controller.method(
   ...
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually set a var on my VF page like this:

```
 var querySomething = '{!$RemoteAction.Ctl_SomeCtrl.querySomething}';
```

Then in my JS file:

```
Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
            querySomething,
            parameterToPass, 
            function(result,event) {
                //do stuff with result
            }
        );
```

You don't need to directly reference the namespace at all. You just can't use the JS remoting shorthand.

Answer (score 0):

For those who stumble upon this post looking for any updates [here is the SFDC recommended approach](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting_namespaces.htm) of doing this

Comment: Yep, thats basically what I did in my answer except I assigned the string to a variable. For me, I like having all my remoting calls assigned to variables so they're all in the same place, makes changing them easier.

Comment: Ditto! Great minds ;)